# Combinatorial proof using P.I.E

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorial-proofs

Use the inclusion-exclusion principle to give a combinatorial proof for the following claim
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k{n \choose k}{n -m\choose k-m} = 0, 1\leq m < n$$.

Will this first choose k elements out of n total elements then choose k elements out of n elements that do not contain m?

Comment: What does "element that does not contain $m$" mean? [hard to see what you intend...]

Comment: This isn't true. For instance, for $m=1$, $n=2$, the left-hand side is $-1$.